# ioerror [Errno 5] after closing terminal ubuntu/gunicorn/nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, pyramid, ioerror

I have a pyramid/python application running on ubuntu/gunicorn/nginx.  When I try to submit a form that sends and email using pyramid_mailer, it works fine if I am connected to server via the terminal.

If I close the terminal window I get an IOError (Errno 5) when I try to send the email.  I should note that everything else on the site works fine but everything that mails out is broken.

I've been trying to troubleshoot but I'm not sure where the problem lies.  I recently upgraded ubuntu and before that I believe it worked okay.

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to fix it by running it as a daemon
Run gunicorn as daemon:
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 runapp --daemon